# Failed to read artifact descriptor for with SpringRoo

Tags: maven-3, spring-roo

I am very new to SpringRooSuit tool.I installed that exe 3.3 release .And I started to create the project .When building my project Its giving the error below:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'HelloWorld'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.4
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.4

My first Question is Do we need to setup the Maven for this?I think maven should hace Embeeded in this exe only. I am new to Maven also.
 If maven has to integrate with STS IDE how to do this...??

Please help me...

Comment: I solved this by changing the version in pom.xml. Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

Came across this issue today so I thought I add exactly what I changed to help anyone else

Changed this from
    `<aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>`
to
    `<aspectj.version>1.7.3</aspectj.version>`

and changed
    `<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>`
    `<version>1.4</version>`
to
    `<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>`
    `<version>1.5</version>`

Project now builds